# How to run an inventory playbook also on servers which Ansible cannot reach?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

My server inventory is stored as a bunch of YML files, one file per server:

```
---

server_data:
  - var_hostname: "linuxbox42"
    var_OS: "Linux"
    var_OS_distro: "RHEL"
    var_OS_version: "9.2"
    (...)
```

I use an Ansible playbook and a Jinja template to generate a CSV of the inventory on the server "linuxbox01".

Playbooks:

```
- name: Create inventory
  hosts: mylinuxservers
  ignore_unreachable: true
  become: true
  gather_facts: yes
  roles:

    - role: linux_create_inventory
```

and

```
- name: Output to CSV
  template:
    src: inventory.csv.j2
    dest: /root/inventory.csv
  delegate_to: linuxbox01
```

J2 template:

```
hostname,OS,OS_distro,OS_version, (...)
{% for h in ansible_play_hosts_all %}
{{
    h 
}},{{ 
    hostvars[h]['server_data'][0]['var_OS'] | default('unknown') 
}},{{
    hostvars[h]['ansible_distribution'] | default(hostvars[h]['server_data'][0]['var_OS_distro'])
}},{{
    hostvars[h]['ansible_distribution_version'] | default(hostvars[h]['server_data'][0]['var_OS_version'])
}},{{
(...)
```

The playbook is run on Ansible Tower (AWX) installed on "linuxbox01".

**Problem:** I need that the CSV contains also the servers which Ansible cannot reach; obviously, Ansible should include for these the static data contained on each YML file, and not the Ansible facts.

Instead, the playbook fails for all servers if there's even one unreachable server:

```
fatal: [linuxbox42 -> linuxbox01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'server_data'"}
fatal: [linuxbox99 -> linuxbox01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'server_data'"}
```

Here, "linuxbox42" is reachable by Ansible but "linuxbox99" isn't.

If I run the playbook on a sublist of servers ("Limit:" on the Ansible Tower job) that are all reachable via Ansible, all goes well and the CSV is generated correctly.

How can I tell Ansible to consider also the YML files for servers which it cannot reach?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, the error raised to you is that `server_data` is not defined for those hosts, are your sure you premises about the inventories files being present for those host is true? BTW, you probably want a [`run_once: true`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-tasks) on this `template` task.

Comment: For the record, here is my trial at reproducing the issue https://gist.github.com/b-enoit-be/3e6055a8865bb6930d3bd6669c54ee31

Comment: Hi @β.εηοιτ.βε, thanks a lot for taking the time of testing it. Yes, the YML inventory files are present for every mentioned server. Can you please explain why should `run_once: true` be added? The template must be run for every server, as each run adds a line to the CSV file.

Comment: It is not the host that are adding new lines to the files, it is written as one file where you are looping on all hosts thanks to your loop `{% for h in ansible_play_hosts_all %}`. If run more than once, the only thing you are doing it overriding the file over and over again.